# iOS SpriteKit strong collision issues

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I wrote few simple SpriteKit games and always had problems with strong collisions behaviour. Even now with my latest game in development the same issue appears quite randomly.

- Game-play area is inside *edgeLoopFromRect* physics body
- There are some objects (with circle physics body) bouncing around

But sometimes (this happens very rarely) when a strong collision (edge <- **body1** <- body2) happens **directly near** the *edgeLoopFromRect* physics body, sometimes colliding-object (**body1**) jumps **out**. I am totally confused how to debug this kind of behaviour.

**EDIT: I have recorded a video of what exactly happens:**

[Physics engine collapses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSXdmUOwBuY)

For the demo I have made impulse strength (the biggest blue ball) on purpose 10-times stronger, so the effect can be seen sooner. Look what happens after 10-15 seconds. Physics totally collapses. This can be seen by background totally going off and balls fly into the unknown.

Note: everything I do in this demo is applying impulse on the blue ball.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `usesPreciseCollisionDetection`.  This will force SpriteKit to calculate the physics positions of the entire movement, which will now prevent it from popping out.  Code for this would look like this in Objective-C:

```
self.body1.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
```

And in Swift:

```
body1.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
```

This will have a performance impact, but will prevent your glitch from happening.  You will probably have to do this for all of the circular physics bodies that you have moving around.

Comment: I have usesPreciseCollisionDetection enabled for all my physics objects - there has to be something else wrong.

Comment: I think we are going to have to see some code in order to debug this further.  From the video, it looks like the edge loop completely goes away, allowing the circles to drop off.  There's not something that detects when a circle leaves, the game ends (and removes the border) right?

Comment: The only thing which is checked (in a simplified demo - I removed most of other objects, checking, etc.) with circle <-> edgeLoop is in beginContact to show smoky-effect at the position where contact happened. And the only user input is to make an impulse (base on direction of swipe) to the blue ball.